# Search an Oracle clob for special characters that are not escaped

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to run a query that can search an Oracle clob for any record that contains an ampersand character where the word in which the character is located in is not one of any of the following (or possible any escape code):

```
 & - &amp;
 < - &lt;
 > - &gt;
 " - &quot;
 ' - &apos;
```

I want to extract 5 character before the ampersand and 5 characters after the ampersand so i can see the actual value. 
Basically i want to search for any record that contains those fields and replace it with the escape code.

At the moment i am doing something like this:

```
Select * from articles 
where dbms_lob.instr(article_summary , '&amp' ) = 0 and dbms_lob.instr(article_summary  , '&' )
```

### Update

If i was to use a regular expression, how would i specify it if i want to retrieve all fields where the value is & followed by any character other than 'a'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlgen.htm#i1012053) for this. The second parameter is optional and if left out will escape the the XML special characters.

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(article_summary)
  from articles;
```

But, if article summary contains a mixture of escaped and unescaped characters, then this will give wrong result. Easiest way to solve it, is to unescape the characters first and then escape it.

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
               DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(article_summary,1)  --1 as parameter does unescaping
                          )
  from articles;
```

Comment: Thanks that is quite useful. What i was looking for was i actually wanted to see the text and not escape it.